# Identificar a URL de entrada de um Filter

Tags: java, servlet, filter, jee

Como faço para identificar por qual `URL` está sendo acessado um filtro?

Minha situação é a seguinte:

Tenho a classe abaixo:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "FiltroLogado", urlPatterns = {"/alterar.jsp",
"/deletar.jsp", "/cadastrado.jsp", "/logado.jsp"})

public class FiltroLogado implements Filter{

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse 
servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, 
ServletException {

HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) 
servletRequest).getSession();

if (session.getAttribute("usuario") == null){
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendRedirect("index.jsp");

}else
    if(){
    ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendRedirect("alterar.jsp");

}

}
```

Quero saber por qual `URL` o filtro está sendo acessado para encaminhar ao lugar específico do link, por exemplo, ao acessar o filtro pela URL `"/alterar.jsp"`, quero que ele vá para `"/alterado.jsp"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse 
servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, 
ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (FAZER CAST) servletRequest;
       if ( request instanceof HttpServletRequest ) {
             String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
             String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
            }

           System.out.println( url + "?" + queryString);
    }

}
```

**você pode fazer um `if` para saber qual pagina e redirecionar.**

Comment: Sim. Minha dúvida era quanto ao método, mas já encontrei. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei o método `getServletPath` para verificar por qual das ***URLs*** o pedido havia entrado.